# SELECT with not equal condition

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How to i display the invoicenumber only if the extended price is not equal to subtotal?

Following query is fail to run and error group function is not allowed here

```
SELECT a.INVOICENUMBER,SUM(a.EXTENDEDPRICE),SUM(a.SUBTOTAL)
FROM CUSTOMERORDERHISTORYVIEW a 
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT a1.INVOICENUMBER FROM CUSTOMERORDERHISTORYVIEW a1 WHERE
a.INVOICENUMBER=a1.INVOICENUMBER AND SUM(a1.EXTENDEDPRICE) <> SUM(a1.SUBTOTAL))
GROUP BY a.INVOICENUMBER;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `having` clause:

```
SELECT a.INVOICENUMBER, SUM(a.EXTENDEDPRICE), SUM(a.SUBTOTAL)
FROM CUSTOMERORDERHISTORYVIEW a 
GROUP BY a.INVOICENUMBER;
HAVING SUM(a.EXTENDEDPRICE) <> SUM(a.SUBTOTAL);
```